# Reiteration in while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

```
var i = 0;
while (i < collection.length) {

  alert(i < collection.length); //true the first time... does not execute the second time

  if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(source))) {
    alert(collection[i][Object.keys(source)]); //executes once
  }

  alert("out" + i); // out 0
  i++;
  alert("out2   " + i); //i is incremented correctly to 1
  alert(collection.length + "    " + i); // 3   1
  alert(i < collection.length); //returns true but does not iterate again.
}
```

I am not able to figure put why this while loop does not reiterate. The alert used show the incrementation of `i` and also that the loop condition is true at end of first iteration. It may be some small error but

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lu9e63jt/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Your collection must have only one element

Comment: there are three objects in collection and my collection.length returns 3. but the loop does not go pass the first one.

Comment: @leoOrion Sidenote: I suggest using `console.log` over `alert`!

Comment: will that help with the loop???!!!

Comment: Are you executing exactly the code shown? I.e., your real code also has that same alert right before the end of the loop?

Comment: yeah it does.. i wanted to check the condition at the end of the loop... But as suggested above i used console.log and it worked out okay.

Comment: But still dont understand why that would make a diffrence???